# How to enable a module on a ResourceTest?

Tags: 9, testing

I'm running a functional test that extends the ResourceTestBase however it is throwing the following error:

`ServiceNotFoundException: The service "cache_tags.invalidator.checksum" has a dependency on a non-existent service "redis.factory".`

the module i'm testing has a dependency on redis and i have included the line:

`protected static $modules = ['user', 'rest', 'redis'];`

In my class but I still get this error.

my test class:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\my_module\Functional\Rest;

use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Tests\rest\Functional\ResourceTestBase;
use GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

/**
 * Tests creation of a user using REST.
 *
 * @group my_module
 */
class myUserCreateTest extends ResourceTestBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected $defaultTheme = 'stark';

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected static $auth = 'basic_auth';

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected static $modules = ['user', 'rest', 'redis'];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setUp(): void {
    parent::setUp();

    $auth = isset(static::$auth) ? [static::$auth] : [];
    $this->provisionResource([static::$format], $auth);

    $this->setUpAuthorization('POST');
  }

  /**
   * Tests user creation
   */
  public function testCreateUser() {
    $create_user_url = Url::fromUserInput('/my-api/my_module/create')
      ->setRouteParameter('_format', static::$format);
    $request_body = [
      "mail" => "mail@mail.com",
      "custom_id" => "12345",
    ];

    $request_options = $this->getAuthenticationRequestOptions('POST');
    $request_options[RequestOptions::BODY] = $this->serialize->encode($request_body, static::$format);
    $request_options[RequestOptions::HEADERS]['Content-Type'] = static::$mimeType;

    $response = $this->request('POST', $create_user_url, $request_options);
    print_r($response);
    $this->assertResourceResponse(200, FALSE, $response);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUpAuthorization($method) {
    switch ($method) {
      case 'POST':
        $this->grantPermissionsToAuthenticatedRole(['restful post create']);
        break;

      default:
        throw new \UnexpectedValueException();
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getExpectedUnauthorizedAccessCacheability() {
    return new CacheableMetadata();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function assertAuthenticationEdgeCases($method, Url $url, array $request_options) {

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function assertNormalizationEdgeCases($method, Url $url, array $request_options) {

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function assertResponseWhenMissingAuthentication($method, ResponseInterface $response) {

  }

}
```

Comment: If you have a `setUp` method, does it call `parent::setUp()`? Also, please provide an entire *minimal* test class that exhibits this issue.

Comment: yes thats the very first thing i do in the setUp method.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I had to comment out the redis configuration settings in settings.php.